# Multiple colors in the same line

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to plot a sine curve in Matlab. But I want it blue for the positive values and red for the negative values.

The following code just makes everything red...

```
x = [];
y = [];
for i = -180 : 180
    x = [x i];
    y = [y sin(i*pi/180)];
end
p = plot(x, y)
set(p, 'Color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot 2 lines with different colours, and `NaN` values at the positive/negative regions

```
% Let's vectorise your code for efficiency too!
x = -pi:0.01:pi; % Linearly spaced x between -pi and pi
y = sin(x);      % Compute sine of x

bneg = y<0;      % Logical array of negative y

y_pos = y; y_pos(bneg) = NaN; % Array of only positive y
y_neg = y; y_neg(~bneg)= NaN; % Array of only negative y

figure; hold on; % Hold on for multiple plots
plot(x, y_neg, 'b'); % Blue for negative
plot(x, y_pos, 'r'); % Red for positive
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

Note: If you're happy with scatter plots, you don't need the `NaN` values. They just act to break the line so you don't get join-ups between regions. You could just do

```
x = -pi:0.01:pi;
y = sin(x);
bneg = y<0;
figure; hold on;
plot(x(bneg), y(bneg), 'b.');
plot(x(~bneg), y(~bneg), 'r.');
```

Output:

[image: output2]

This is so clear because my points are only `0.01` apart. Further spaced points would appear more like a scatter plot.

Comment: you could instead just do `y_pos=y(y>0);x_pos=x(y>0);` and use plot without NaNs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's like what I did at the bottom, no? The argument for using NaNs is that if, say, you plot over `x = -3*pi:0.01:3*pi` then you get multiple regions, and the last/first points of each region will be connected if they aren't separated by `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, yes, its like you did. Sorry just thinking about doing it without the scatter and got lost in my thoughts. +1

Comment: Just mention that the OP wanted the _positive_ part to be blue... but that's a nice answer.

Comment: @EBH yeah I realised that after I posted, but didn't have time to redo the images :) cheers