# I want to plot line with 3 colors on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, line

I have 3 variables, x, y, z.
I want to plot line with 3 colors, red at h=0, green at h=1, blue at h=2.

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14];
y = [0 1 2 1 3 4 7 9 8 6 5 3 2 1 0];
h = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2];
color = [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Multiple colors in the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225810/multiple-colors-in-the-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14];
y = [0 1 2 1 3 4 7 9 8 6 5 3 2 1 0];
h = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2];
color = [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1];


greens = h<1;
reds = h>=1;
blues = h>=2;

greenLine = y;
redLine = y;
blueLine = y;


greenLine(~greens) = NaN;

redLine(~reds) = NaN

blueLine(~blues) = NaN

plot(x,greenLine,'g',x,redLine,'r',x,blueLine,'b');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well just after change from "xxxLine = h" to "xxxLine = y" :)